# Does a closed form for this specific integer sequence exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

For a bigger project, I would like to identify a closed form for this integer sequence:

$$2, 17, 47, 92, 152, 227, 317, 422, 542, 677, 827, ...$$

I had some success on Sloane's integer sequences, where [A025705](https://oeis.org/A025705) definitely shows a clear rhythm.

[image]

This series shows the index of powers of $4$ in a series that is built from $4^i\cdot10^j$, $(i,j\ge 0)$. That ordered series is listed as [A025621](https://oeis.org/A025621).

Does anyone see how I could get an $a(n)$ formula for my series?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe look for a common difference.

Comment: How was your sequence originally defined or computed?

Comment: Great suggestion. Just after posting the question I suddenly spotted a sequence in the difference! Pretty stupid I didn't see it before...

Comment: It goes up from $2$ by $15,30,45,60...$, how could I have missed it :-(

Comment: This formula: $\left\lfloor \frac{(k-1)(k+4)+25}{10} \right\rfloor$ generates A025621, so supplying $k=5n+1$, starting with $n=0$ will give the desired sequence in the OP

Comment: @Χpẘ. Thanks. Are you sure this formula is correct for series A025621 ? I tried it, however do get a different outcome (I assume the brackets indicate the floor function, right?).

Comment: Oops, typo. Should be $\left\lfloor \frac{3(k-1)(k+4)+25}{10} \right\rfloor$. I tested this for all the values listed in OEIS ($0\dots 57$).

Comment: Thanks. That works. Do you have a proof it works for all k? Especially in the context of Ivan's comment below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As observed by me $$a_n=a+\frac{15n(n-1)}{2}$$ because I saw that there are  multiple of $15$ increasing in the difference of consecutive terms

Comment: Thanks Atul. I spotted it as well. Sometimes just the process of posting on StackExchange does the trick. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: yeah, many times happened with me too, lol

Comment: Ahh. But why? And what about bases other than 4 and 10?

Comment: @marty. That is a great question indeed. The author who published  the sequence at Sloane's also published similar series for e.g. $2^i,10^j$. Haven't checked for other patterns. Maybe they do exist.

Comment: The pattern with $4^i10^j$ is apparently caused by $4^5\approx10^3$, and will inevitably break at some point.