# Does a closed form exist for this specific triangle of numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

As part of a bigger project, I need to find a closed form for this triangle of numbers below:
[image]

Note that in each incremental row (let's label them $n=1,2,3,...$), a new sequence starts with $\dfrac{1}{\pi^2},\dfrac{1}{\pi^4},\dfrac{1}{\pi^6},...$ multiplied by a rational. These sequences are the columns of the triangle (let's label them $k=0,1,2,3..$). I already did manage to find for cells $TT[n,k]$ (the $\frac{1}{\pi^{2m}}$'s are left out for simplicity, I am primarily after the rationals):

$TT[n,0]= \small 2^{2n-0}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)}$

$TT[n,1]= \small 2^{2n-1}\cdot\dfrac{n}{(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)}$

$TT[n,2]= \small 2^{2n-2}\cdot\dfrac{n\,(3n-1)}{(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)(2n-4)(2n-5)}$

$TT[n,3]= \small 2^{2n-3}\cdot\dfrac{n\,(15n^2-15n+4)}{(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)(2n-4)(2n-5)(2n-6))(2n-7)}$ (with help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338397/does-a-closed-form-for-this-specific-integer-sequence-exist)).

$TT[n,4]= \small 2^{2n-4}\cdot\dfrac{n\,(???)}{(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)(2n-4)(2n-5)(2n-6))(2n-7)(2n-8)(2n-9)}$

It might also be the case that the cells in this triangle could be constructed top-down with a formula like: $TT[n+1,k+1] = x(n)\cdot[TT[n,k+1] \pm y(n)\cdot TT[n,k]$, however I have not been able to spot the rhythm.

I'd be highly grateful for any help on how to potentially progress this.

Thanks!

Comment: It will likely help to describe this "bigger project" and where these numbers are coming from. Without that, this community would be no more help than OEIS. If you don't think this is necessary, that's fine too, but just so you know more help may come from that direction.

Comment: Appreciate and understand the feedback, Bob. I was actually planning to post the full context of the question, however it consists of a long series of closed forms that I have already found. I actually just need this final one to complete the story. If it doesn't get cracked by the community in the next few days, I'll follow you advice and post the full context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into $TT[n,k]$ formulas, it seems that they follow a pattern,

So judging on the previous ones that you managed to find a closed form which are $TT[n,0],TT[n,1],TT[n,2],TT[n,3]$, its easy to see that $???$ you are looking for is a cubic equation of the form $a x^3 +b x^2 +c x +d$.

And since you have a lot of data (at least four equations with four variables $a,b,c,d$) you can easily find them (Using Wolfram) or any other Software.

So Assuming all the above i found using Wolfram|Alpha that  the $???$ is equal to the cubic polynomial $105n^3-210n^2+147n-34$.

Testing the result with your data and i found a perfect match.

Comment: Excellent Ahmad and many thanks! Did you spot any other pattern in the data or maybe in the polynomials (I was hoping they might be factored in some smart way)?

Comment: @Agno the coefficient of the leading power in the polynomials have the sequence $1,3,15,105,945,\cdots$ which is $\prod 2k-1 $ so the $TT[n,5]$ will have the leading term $945n^4$ but other than that i could not find any thing useful.

Comment: I just did find something! Check out this OEIS series: https://oeis.org/A094665. I believe it has all the coefficients of all the polynomials. If right, I conjecture the TT[n,5] polynomial is: $945 n^4-3150 n^3+4095 n^2-2370 n+496$. Just checked and it works perfectly :-) This is even better than I expected.

Comment: @Agno very good, i think you found what you are looking for, at least now you can attach your project for related math online.

Comment: I will post the full version soon indeed (probably on MO, will link it to here). You put me on the right track, Ahmad. Thanks again!

Comment: Have now posted the full question here. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273375/another-integral-that-has-a-closed-form-involving-finite-series-of-zeta2k1 Fingers crossed.