# What is the location of $a^n$ in the sequence of values of $a^i b^j$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

What is the
location of
$a^n$
in the sequence of
values of
$a^i b^j$?
I would be quite satisfied
with an approximate answer.

This question
is inspired by
[Does a closed form for this specific integer sequence exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338397/does-a-closed-form-for-this-specific-integer-sequence-exist).

I have made some
exploratory observations,
but they don't seem to
be leading to an answer.
Here they are.

Note:
All variables are positive integers.

Let
$N(n)$
be the number of solutions of
$1 \le a^ib^j \le n$.

Then
$0 \le i\ln(a)+j\ln(b)
\le \ln(n)
$.
This is the
number of lattice points
in a right triangle
with sides
$\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(a)}$
and
$\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(b)}$
which is about
$\frac{\ln^2(n)}{2\ln(a)\ln(b)}
$.

Want the inverse function, 
at least approximately.
If
$\frac{\ln^2(n)}{c}
= \ln(m)
$,
then
$\ln(n)
=\sqrt{c\ln(m)}
$.
This says that
the $m$-th value
of ths form
$a^ib^j$
is about
$\sqrt{2\ln(a)\ln(b)\ln(a^ib^j)}
=\sqrt{2\ln(a)\ln(b)(i\ln(a)+j\ln(b))}
$.

The exponent of
the largest power of $a$
less than $n$,
$p_a(n)
\sim\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(a)}
$.

(That's all, folks)

Comment: What is the definition of "location" in a doubly indexed sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Consider how the sequence $a,a^2,a^3,\cdots $ is interleafed into the sequence $b,b^2,b^3,\cdots $. (for the sake of what is written below we assume $b << a$, but the arguement will still work, without loss of generality)
\begin{eqnarray*}
b,\cdots,b^{j_1^{+}},a, b^{j_1^{+}},\cdots,b^{j_2^{+}},a^2, b^{j_2^{+}},\cdots,b^{j_k^{+}},a^k, b^{j_k^{+}},\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply this by a power of $a$ and look for where $a^n$ "fits best". Equivalently, let $k_-$ and $k_+$ be defined to be the $i$ value(s) where the following maximum and minimums occur
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max_{i=1 \cdots n} (a^{n-i}b^{j_i^{-}}) \\
\min_{i=1 \cdots n} (a^{n-i}b^{j_i^{+}}) 
\end{eqnarray*}
The best position for $a^n$ is then $ a^{n-k_{-}}b^{j_{k_-}^{-}} < a^n < a^{n-k_{+}}b^{j_{k_+}^{+}}$.